# Square brackets in name attribute of input tag

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I see a lot of time there is square brackets in the name attribute of input tag. What is it for and why it's used?

```
   `input id="academy_name" name="academy[name]" size="30" type="text" />`
```

So why name="academy[name]" and not just name="academy".

Please help!

Comment: It wrape name in academy hash so when you do param[:academy] it will give yo all attribute for academy object

Answer (score 2):

It is because the developer is using array, and hence he is wrapping the names in `[]` bar brackets

Comment: In the case of RoR it doesn't indicate Array notation on the form.  It indicates that the `name` attribute belongs to the `academy` object.  When the form is posted back, it maps the attributes in the `academy` object to the respective attributes.

Answer (score 0):

RoR maps the attributes of models within the model name, so that when you post the form you can assign them easily, such as:

```
Academy.create(params[:academy])
```

or

```
@academy = Academy.find(params[:id])
@academy.update_attributes(params[:academy]
```

(also known as mass assignment).

If you inspect the `academy` object with it is sent to the form in the `params` hash, you will see that it has an element for each of the things contained in the square brackets.