# My file input value has value even if I clear it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, file

As you see in the screenshot. I choose a file, leave the pop up without refreshing the page and open it again, and the file input still has the file I picked.

```html
<input id="fileuploadbannermobile" type="file" name="files[]">
```

I try this when the pop up opened.

```js
$("#fileuploadbannermobile").val('');
```

But it doesn't seem to solve the issue.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Could you create a runnable snippet (and test that it does show the problem) thanks. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Also, use trigger('change'); Like :: $("#file").val('').trigger('change');

Comment: The code you have [should work fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617738/how-to-clear-file-input). If it doesn't, it is something else you haven't shown here causing problems. How/when do you fire the reset?

Answer (score 1):

Setting an input value to empty string or null should definitely work.

- try setting a value to "" or null in vanila javascript

  `yourInput.value = null` or `yourInput.value = ""`
- also check if you are setting those values to the right input

It would also be useful to know what browser you use.

Comment: <input id="fileuploadbannermobile" type="file" name="files[]">   thats my file input btw. maybe other attributes are the problem

Comment: @Mert first, name can not be a list. I prepared you a fiddle, try it:
[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/pf68sgzv/)

Comment: @AndrejNovák Why do you think plain JS will work when jQuery does not, I mean what do you think the problem is?  Also, a `name` with square brackets like `files[]` is perfectly valid ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175347/how-can-i-select-and-upload-multiple-files-with-html-and-php-using-http-post), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854259/square-brackets-in-name-attribute-of-input-tag), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946450/why-do-i-use-brackets-in-the-name-attribute-of-input-element),  ...)

Comment: @Don'tPanic you are right, i completely forget about that. 
"what do you think the problem is?" - at this point i can not be certain. Author did not provided the code where he is registering/executing events (during pop up opening), my guess is that the value setting is not triggered in any way.